# verifiy email with firebase swift xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im trying to see if an email has been verified by firebase then call code but i can't get  emailVerified to work/ i get the error no member emailVerified

has it been changed / can anyone give me the sample code?

my related code below:

```
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }


    if uid.emailVerified == true {

print("working")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to send the email verification. You can do that like this:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

You can check if a user has verified their email like this:

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    if user.isEmailVerified {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email)